# Pull through just a template and not the whole site via ajax

Tags: module, magento-1, template, ajax

I am creating an attribute filter. When you click on an attribute value I would like an ajax request to pull through just the part of the module that displays the product list. However, I am getting the entire site fired back to me through console!

In my index controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{ 

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list');
        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();            

    }
}
```

How can I just push through the product_list block?

Any help is appreciated.

--- UPDATE ----

I did it like this... is this the best way?

```
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->loadLayout();
        echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('toxicfox.giftfinder.view')->getChildHtml('product_list');


    } else {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();            
      }
```

Comment: You may want to write your update as an answer. This is how I usually do it and it worked so far without issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great example for this kind of functionality is the onepage checkout, for instance the piece that loads just the sidebar content:

controller:

```
public function progressAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->loadLayout(false);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

checkout.xml

```
<checkout_onepage_progress>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_progress>
```

The trick is `$this->loadLayout(false)` and `name="root" output="toHtml"`.

You can create a controller and a layout xml tag for your ajax response and set the block that you want to display as `name="root"`.

Comment: Nice job on the extra explanation. Makes it more comprehensible!

Comment: No problem. I think we cross-posted by the way. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set this block as the root element in your layout XML which will cause only this block to return

```
<your_extension_handle>
  <block type="toxicfox/giftfinder_view" name= "root" template="template/toxicfox/giftfinder/view.phtml"/>
</your_extension_handle>
```

This does however mean that you need a controller that loads this handle. If not you need to create one in, for example, the `IndexController`.

Your handle would be `toxicfox_index_ajax` and in the `IndexController` the method would be

```
[...]
public function ajaxAction()
{
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();   
}
[...]
```

Then calling the ajax via `http://domain.com/toxicfox/index/ajax/`